# Using Bootstrap in LANSA

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ibm-midrange, lansa

I am working on a project where we are using LANSA, AXES, and RAMP tools for modernizing the AS400 application into the web, which typically does a screen scraping of the AS400 screen and converts it into an HTML page. So far, we are using the native CSS provided by LANSA to design the web pages.

I want to know if is it recommended to use external CSS like Bootstrap to design web pages using LANSA. If yes, will there be any consequences of Bootstrap's use, when we move our application into production, I mean if we are using Bootstrap in production, will it cause any performance problems?

I also want to tweak the native CSS provided by LANSA with Bootstrap CSS, will this cause any problems?

Since LANSA is a commercial product, will it be a copyright violation to use external CSS?

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about licensing violation issues of LANSA commercial product with open source solutions like bootstrap, I can suggest to look at OpenLegacy open source modernization solution which is designed from bottom up for developing responsive applications (using bootstrap) based on AS/400 screens,  including LANSA as400 applications.

Disclaimer : I am the CTO and project leader of OpenLegacy